# Convergence in probability of a discrete variable

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

> Let there be a sequence of r.v.'s $\{X_{n}\}$ with the following property
>   \begin{align}
> \mathbb{P}(X_n = n)
>    = 1 - \mathbb{P}\left(X_{n} = \frac{1}{n}\right)
>    = \frac{1}{n^{2}}
> \end{align}
>   Show that $X_{n} \xrightarrow[]{\mathbb{P}} 0$.

Usually I define $$\lim_{n \xrightarrow[]{}\infty}\mathbb{P}(|X_{n}-X| > \epsilon)\; \forall \epsilon,$$ in this case $X = 0$, and apply Chebyshev's inequality to get a upper bound and see where it leads me, however I'm struggling with this one, I would appreciate a insight on finding the variance. Also the author does not define the distribution support, is this a mistake? Can we solve the problem without this information? Applying the limit to the probability would get me the result, but is it correct?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $1/n<\epsilon<n$, then $P(|X_n|>\epsilon)=1/n^2 \to 0$. This inequality holds for a fixed $\epsilon>0$ for all sufficiently large $n$.

The choice of $n,1/n$ and $1/n^2$ was not essential, you could have had $P(X_n=x_n)=1-P(X_n=y_n)=p_n$ for any sequence $x_n$, any sequence $y_n \to 0$, and any sequence $p_n \to 0$.

Note that the distribution support is already specified because the two given probabilities sum to $1$.

Comment: So let met see if I understood, as specified, $X_{n}$ can take only 2 values for a fixed $n$, $1/n$ and $n$, so if $n >\epsilon > 1/n$, which holds when $n$ goes to $\infty$, only $n$ remains as a possible choice, therefore $P(|X_{n} |>\epsilon) = P(X_{n} = n)$, correct? =)

Comment: @SergioAndrade That's correct.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: let $0\lt \varepsilon\lt 1$. Show that $\left\{\left\lvert X_n\right\rvert\gt \varepsilon\right\}=\left\{  X_n=n\right\}$.